# Deny any access by `anonymous` in WildFly

Tags: security, jax-rs, wildfly, undertow, elytron

I'd like to prevent the unidentified user `anonymous` to access anything in my WildFly application server.

All of my users are managed in an LDAP server. Some have special roles with extra privileges so they can access methods annotated as `@RolesAllowed`. Some methods don't need such a special role and should be accessible by *all* users, except for `anonymous`.

Of course I could introduce a role like `User` and grant that to all users, but I'd rather have a general rule to globally exclude `anonymous`.

Looking at the [Elytron docs](https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html) didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the special role-name `*` in a `security-contstaint` of your `web.xml`, which matches any role name, but fails on users without any roles, i.e. `anonymous`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>*</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Note: My IDE complains about `*` not being a valid `NMTOKEN`, but it works.